# Jquery mobile redirect doesnt work

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-mobile

Through php i want to redirect the user to specific location :

```
header('Location:http://localhost/diplomska/#more')
```

and the url in the browser after redirect  is :

```
http://localhost/diplomska/#more
```

But it still points to the home page. Even if i manualy write it in the browser, it is still the same. However, if i click the navigation link that go to the page `#more` , it works.
I have added `data-url` attribute, but still the same . Code in addition:

```
<div id = "more" data-role="page" data-url="http://localhost/diplomska/#more"data-title="More about you" >
```

And the link that work when i click on it is :

```
<a id="more" href="#more"
    data-transation="slidedown"
    data-role="button"
    data-icon="arrow-d"
    data-mini="true"
    data-iconpos="top"
    >More</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't have more than one element with a given `id` on a page. Remove the `id` from your `anchor`, it's `href` attribute references the `div` you want to jump to.